# How can I apply CSS properties to dynamic generated HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am trying to create a list of colours based on a list of objects. My issue is how to dynamically set the `background-color` of each `li` created based on the `data.corporate.colour.hex`. I tried a few things without success. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/bRBpKQ?editors=0010)

```js
var data = {
  corporate: [{
      name: "blue",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 0, 25, 168",
        hex: "0019A8"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "red",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 145, 25, 168",
        hex: "00eeA8"
      }
    }
  ]
};

var output = [];

for (var i in data.corporate) {
  output.push("<li>" +
    data.corporate[i].name + " " +
    data.corporate[i].colour.rgb + "--" +
    data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "</li>");
}

console.log(output);

$("#placeholder").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="placeholder"></ul>
```

Comment: "style='background-color:#"+data.corporate[i].hex+"'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173229/how-do-i-write-a-rgb-color-value-in-javascript

Comment: you can add classes to it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

`"<li class='colour' style='color:#" + data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "'>"`

```js
var data = {
  corporate: [{
      name: "blue",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 0, 25, 168",
        hex: "0019A8"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "red",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 145, 25, 168",
        hex: "00eeA8"
      }
    }
  ]
};

var output = [];

for (var i in data.corporate) {
  output.push("<li class='colour' style='color:#" + data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "'>" +
    data.corporate[i].name + " " +
    data.corporate[i].colour.rgb + "--" +
    data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "</li>");
}
$("#placeholder").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="placeholder"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below snippet

```js
var data = {
  corporate: [{
      name: "blue",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 0, 25, 168",
        hex: "0019A8"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "red",
      colour: {
        rgb: "RGB 145, 25, 168",
        hex: "00eeA8"
      }
    }
  ]
};

var output = [];

for (var i in data.corporate) {
  output.push("<li style='background-color:#" + data.corporate[i].colour.hex +"'>" +
    data.corporate[i].name + " " +
    data.corporate[i].colour.rgb + "--" +
    data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "</li>");
}

console.log(output);

$("#placeholder").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="placeholder"> </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://codepen.io/F1ks3r/pen/vZyKVP) what you tried to achieve?

Ive added
`style='background-color: #"+ data.corporate[i].colour.hex + "'`
to your component

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the logic that you are using already by dynamically generating html elements, and after you have access to the created `<li>`'s, you can loop over them at any point in the same, I assume `.js` file like so.

```
var lis = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('placeholder').childNodes); 

lis.forEach(function(li) {
   li.style.color = // whatever
   li.style['background-color'] = // whatever
});
```

This would let you set the color to whatever you want whenever you want (i.e. create animations and alternating colors if you need to or update colors based on events too), since javascript allows you to access the `style` property of an html element whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will definitely use this in the future.